# Angular *ngFor cache images and array filtering

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngfor, image-caching

My application renders a list of object where i use image url to render it.

```
<app-post *ngFor='let post of posts' [imageUrl]="post.imageUrl"></app-post>
```

I get the objects from a store like this:

```
this.store.pipe(select(selectPosts), takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((posts) => {
  this.posts = posts;
});
```

The posts array looks like:

```
[
  {id: 112, imageUrl: "http://image1.com/img1.png", status: 'pending'},
  {id: 113, imageUrl: "http://image1.com/img2.png", status: 'approved'},
  {id: 114, imageUrl: "http://image1.com/img3.png", status: 'declined'}
]
```

1. How to filter objects from store properly? I do like this:

```
filterPostsByStatus(status: string): void {
    this.store
      .pipe(select(selectPosts), takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe((posts) => {
        if (status === 'all') {
          return (this.posts = posts);
        }
        return (this.posts = posts.filter((post) => post.status === status));
      })
      .unsubscribe();
  }
```

Is this right way to filter objects from a store?

2. More important, whenever i do this, the browser downloads images every time (I filter 50, 100 items) and this leads to number of images requests to a server.
   How can I filter the objects array and do not make images requests to a server whenever i filter the array?

p.s. I see the cache-control: max-age=0 for images from a server. Can this be a reason that the browser downloads them every time?

Comment: Yeah I think the cache-control is screwing you over. I can't see a way to override it at the browser level, but you can manually manage your images at the application level. This [article](https://sonigaurav119.medium.com/cache-images-in-angular-43964e26ff62) explains how quite nicely. With a little tinkering you can preload them too, so your app will should run very smoothly.

Comment: It's not ideal, but if you don't own the server that serves the images, and you can't override the browser behaviour, then I think it's the only way.

Comment: Look at an approach like this using a custom pipe: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-todos?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts - your implementation is questionable, particularly short term subscriptions to selectors and even assigning to variables within those subscribes - use of async pipe is much preferable.